# Compile ikvmc pw-swift-core-XXXX.jar as clr .dll

Tags: java, .net, dll, ikvm

I try to compile pw-swift-core-SRU2014-7.6-B1410151122.jar as a `cld .dll` with `ikvmc` tool (IKVM.NET), but I have many warnings.

---

cmd:

```
D:\WIFE_DOTNET\ikvm-7.2.4630.5\bin>ikvmc -target:library -sharedclassloader pw-swift-core-SRU2014-7.6-B1410151122.jar commons-lang-2.6.jar js.jar xbean.jar
```

result:

```
IKVM.NET Compiler version 7.2.4630.5
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Jeroen Frijters
http://www.ikvm.net/

note IKVMC0002: Output file is "pw-swift-core-SRU2014-7.6-B1410151122.dll"
warning IKVMC0109: Skipping class: "javax.xml.namespace.QName"
    (class is already available in referenced assembly "IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.API,    
    Version=7.2.4630.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58")
warning IKVMC0105: Unable to compile class "org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean"
    (missing class "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MatchingTask")
warning IKVMC0100: Class "org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "org.apache.tools.ant.Project" not found
warning IKVMC0111: Emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in     
    "org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean$ErrorLogger.<init>   
    (Lorg.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean;Z)V"
    ("org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean")
warning IKVMC0111: Emitted java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in 
    "org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean$ErrorLogger.add(Ljava.lang.Object;)Z"
    ("org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.XMLBean")
```

Comment: Hi have you found a solution to your problem? because I have the same problem. thank you